Pydantic Dependent Schema
class LocationRequest(BaseModel):
    business_unit: Optional[str] = None
    opening: Optional[int]
    max_applicant: Optional[int]
    diversity_male: Optional[int]
    diversity_female: Optional[int]


class JobRoleRequest(BaseModel):
    name: str
    description: Optional[str] = None
    work_mode: Literal["full time", "half day"]


class JobRoleCreateRequest(JobRoleRequest):

    location: List[LocationRequest]


while adding null value for integer fields in sub-schema location:  List[LocationRequest] but for business_unit when i leave it is working
Need possible ways to add null value for sub-schema fields
Sample Request schema
{
    "name": "Job role",
    "description": "job role description",
    "work_mode": "Remote",
    "location": [
        {
            "business_unit": "busiess_unit of company 1",
            "opening": 10,
            "max_applicant": 4,
            "diversity_male": 2
            "diversity_female": 2,
        }
    ]
}

If I pass the location list without optional fields like max_applicant or diversity_male, it should work. However, when I try to pass it without these fields, I'm getting an error.

Could you please explain what output you would like to have and with what input? It's not really clear from your description what you would like to do.

@VictorEgiazarian I had updated the content

Thank you, but can you please show, how you build your model from dict? Optional[int] means that your field can have None value, but it is still has to be specified explicitly. Optional[int] = None means that you have already provided default value and can skip explicit initialization.

@VictorEgiazarian I had also tired with the below code but still the issue exists -----
opening: Optional[int] = Field(ge=0, le=999, default=0)
max_applicant: Optional[int] = Field(ge=0, le=999, default=0)
diversity_male: Optional[int] = Field(ge=0, le=999, default=0)

You can check pydantic's docs: Required, optional, and nullable fields
Non required, nullable fields
If you want to define your field as a non required nullable field, you can simply set a default value:
max_applicant: Optional[int] = None

And if don't inform the field:
sample = {
    "name": "Job role",
    "description": "job role description",
    "work_mode": "half day",
    "location": [
        {
            "business_unit": "busiess_unit of company 1",
            "opening": 10,
            "diversity_male": 2,
            "diversity_female": 2
        }
    ]
}

print(JobRoleCreateRequest(**sample))
# name='Job role' description='job role description' work_mode='half day' location=[LocationRequest(business_unit='busiess_unit of company 1', opening=10, max_applicant=None, diversity_male=2, diversity_female=2)]

You'll get your default value for max_applicant.
The same applies if you pass "max_applicant": null in json.
Note that this (got from your comments) is the same:
opening: Optional[int] = Field(0, ge=0, le=999)

Optional[int] = Field(0) means that this field is optional, will have the default value of 0 if not present, but if it is passed can be both an integer ou a null.
Required, but can be null
It's exactly how you defined your fields. When you define a field as optional, but without giving a default value, you are saying to pydantic that this field is required when creating the model, but if the value of the field is None, that's ok:
sample = {
    "name": "Job role",
    "description": "job role description",
    "work_mode": "half day",
    "location": [
        {
            "business_unit": "busiess_unit of company 1",
            "opening": None, # still required to inform, but can be null
            "max_applicant": None, # still required to inform, but can be null
            "diversity_male": None, # still required to inform, but can be null
            "diversity_female": None # still required to inform, but can be null
        }
    ]
}

print(JobRoleCreateRequest(**sample))
# name='Job role' description='job role description' work_mode='half day' location=[LocationRequest(business_unit='busiess_unit of company 1', max_applicant=None, opening=None, diversity_male=None, diversity_female=None)]

Optional, but non nullable
If you want your field to be optional, but can't be null, you can define it as:
opening: int = Field(ge=0, le=999, default=0)

This way, you are telling pydantic that opening field is not required to be informed, and it will have de default value of 0 if it's not present, but if it is present, it needs to be a non nullable integer.
Non required, nullable but with non nullable default value
If you want your field to be optional, to be possible to pass a null value, but to have a non nullable value if null is passed, you can use field_validator:
opening: Optional[int] = Field(0, ge=0, le=999)

@field_validator("opening")
@classmethod
def assign_default_if_none(cls, v: Optional[int]) -> int:
    return v or 0 # return your default value here

This way, if you payload has "opening": None, opening won't be null anymore, it will be assigned the default value, or 0 in this case:
class LocationRequest(BaseModel):
    business_unit: Optional[str] = None
    max_applicant: Optional[int]
    opening: Optional[int] = Field(0, ge=0, le=999)
    diversity_male: Optional[int]
    diversity_female: Optional[int]

    @field_validator("opening")
    @classmethod
    def assign_default_if_none(cls, v: Optional[int]) -> int:
        return v or 0


class JobRoleRequest(BaseModel):
    name: str
    description: Optional[str] = None
    work_mode: Literal["full time", "half day"]


class JobRoleCreateRequest(JobRoleRequest):

    location: List[LocationRequest]


sample = {
    "name": "Job role",
    "description": "job role description",
    "work_mode": "half day",
    "location": [
        {
            "business_unit": "busiess_unit of company 1",
            "opening": None,
            "max_applicant": None,
            "diversity_male": None,
            "diversity_female": None
        }
    ]
}

print(JobRoleCreateRequest(**sample))
# name='Job role' description='job role description' work_mode='half day' location=[LocationRequest(business_unit='busiess_unit of company 1', max_applicant=None, opening=0, diversity_male=None, diversity_female=None)

Obs
Obs: In your example payload, you are passing "work_mode": "Remote" while work_mode can be only "full time" or "half day".
